# Right way to reverse a VM

Tags: ida, disassembly, decompile, virtualizers, vm

I'm currently reversing a virtualized sample  that uses a custom **VM bytecode**. After defeating the anti-disassembly tricks I'm finally faced with the `vm_dispatch` function. I have to figure out the custom vm opcodes in order to determine what the program actually does. Unlike most other vms, there are no `vftables` which makes it very hard for me to reverse since there are more than 100 virtual handlers which are not defined as functions (All of the handlers are defined in `loc_XXXX` code blocks. Example image is below).

[image]

Trying to decompile the `vm_dispatch` function leaves me with this:

```
  ...
  a lot of local variable initialization
  ...
  assign vm handlers
  ...
  bytecode_array[53] = &loc_4041A3;
  regs->VIP = 0x6000;  // virtual ip
  memcpy(bytecode_array + regs->VIP, bytecode, bytecode_size);
  regs->R5 = -1;
  vm_code = *(bytecode_array + regs->VIP++);
  __asm { jmp     [ebp+eax*4+vm_handler_array]; jump to the appropriate handler }// switch jmp
}
```

I know it's not fully decompiled because there are more than 100 blocks, each executing a specific vm bytecode. None of that is reflected on the decompiler output.

It's really time-consuming to go through each `loc_XXXX` without being able to define VM specific structures like `VM` and `REG` and to read the low-level assembly. My question is, is there any:

- Way to convert `loc_XXXX` code blocks to functions to that I can decompile the code and create structures?
- Right approach to read the assembly / make it easier?